# Restore a postgres backup file using the command line?

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line, backup, restore

Locally, I use pgadmin3.  On the remote server, however, I have no such luxury.

I've already created the backup of the database and copied it over, but is there a way to restore a backup from the command line? I only see things related to GUI or to pg_dumps.

Answer (score 681, accepted):

There are two tools to look at, depending on how you created the dump file.

Your first source of reference should be the man page [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) as that is what creates the dump itself.  It says:

> Dumps can be output in script or
> archive file formats. Script dumps are
> plain-text files containing the SQL
> commands  required  to  reconstruct
> the  database  to  the  state  it  was
> in at the time it was saved. To
> restore from such a script, feed it to
> psql(1).  Script  files  can  be used
> to  reconstruct  the  database  even
> on other machines and other
> architectures; with some modifications
> even on other SQL database products.
>
> The alternative archive file formats
> must be used with pg_restore(1) to
> rebuild the database. They allow
> pg_restore to be selective about  what
> is restored, or even to reorder the
> items prior to being restored.  The
> archive file formats are designed to
> be portable across  architectures.

So depends on the way it was dumped out. If using Linux/Unix, you can probably figure it out using the excellent `file(1)` command - if it mentions ASCII text and/or SQL, it should be restored with [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) otherwise you should probably use [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html).

Restoring is pretty easy:

```
psql -U username -d dbname < filename.sql

-- For Postgres versions 9.0 or earlier
psql -U username -d dbname -1 -f filename.sql
```

or

```
pg_restore -U username -d dbname -1 filename.dump
```

Check out their respective manpages - there's quite a few options that affect how the restore works.  You may have to clean out your "live" databases or recreate them from template0 (as pointed out in a comment) before restoring, depending on how the dumps were generated.

Comment: IME you practically always want to restore into a database that has been newly-created from template0. Otherwise if you've done something like activating plpgsql in template1, the restore process will try to do it again, and the -1 switch you suggest means the whole transaction will fail.

So something like "createdb -T template0 seo2" followed by "pg_restore -v -d seo2 seo.pg" to restore seo.pg (made from the seo database) into a new seo2 database.

If your backup file is just a .sql file, you can trim conflicting bits of it out by hand.

Comment: Sometimes the dump explicitly drops the database and recreates it.  But good point :-)

Comment: How I put password into this template0?

Comment: You cannot have `-d` and `-f` at the same time. `pg_restore: options -d/--dbname and -f/--file cannot be used together
`

Comment: In version 9.2 the "-f" option specifies an output file, not the dump file (and it probably means the same in earlier versions).

Comment: @araqnid - ta buddy.  I tried what s in the answer but it complained you can't use -d and -f in one command.  Your version worked.  nice and easy to remember also.

Comment: this didn't work for me, best answer should have been the one from pilot

Comment: Regarding `cannot be used together`, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882070/why-does-pg-restore-return-options-d-dbname-and-f-file-cannot-be-used-tog

Comment: psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U myUsername mydbname< myDumpFile.dump

Comment: @Alex78191 it means it executes as a single transaction, which could completely fail and rollback, or go through. It will block some access to the database also.

Comment: Can we add verbose to this restore command if yes please let me know-how?

Comment: `psql -U USERNAME -d DBNAME -1 -f FILENAME.sql` failed with syntax errors where as `psql -U USERNAME -d DBNAME < FILENAME.sql` worked.

Comment: I am not sure why this was voted up at all.  A working pg_dump command that will work with the `psql` or `pg_restore` command is not even included.  This is not an adequate, fully working example of anything helpful.  Delete this answer, people clicked to upvote, not even trying this.  sloppy.

Comment: To me, using [`\i or \include filename`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) worked better than `-f`.

Comment: You probably need to create the new database which you're dumping into before you can restore: `createdb -U username dbname`

Comment: can we add how to dump in this answer?

Answer (score 331):

**create backup**

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f 
"/usr/local/backup/10.70.0.61.backup" old_db
```

`-F c` is *custom format* (compressed, and able to do in parallel with `-j N`) `-b` is *including blobs*, `-v` is *verbose*, `-f` is the *backup file name*.

**restore from backup**

```
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d old_db -v 
"/usr/local/backup/10.70.0.61.backup"
```

*important to set `-h localhost` - option*

Comment: I'd like to mention that before you execute these commands you should be located in the Posgresql **bin** folder. For example in Windows (if you installed it in the default folder)  it would be **C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin**

Comment: @juan_carlos_yl Or make sure the bin directory is on your PATH

Comment: >-F c is custom format (compressed, and able to do in parallel with -j N)
This is wrong, only directory format support parallel dump

Comment: `pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v old_db -f  "/usr/local/backup/10.70.0.61.backup"`

I find it more intuitive if tis written this way

Answer (score 143):

You might need to be logged in as `postgres` in order to have full privileges on databases.

```
su - postgres
psql -l                      # will list all databases on Postgres cluster
```

**pg_dump/pg_restore**

```
  pg_dump -U username -f backup.dump database_name -Fc
```

switch `-F` specify format of backup file:

- `c` will use custom PostgreSQL format which is compressed and results in smallest backup file size
- `d` for directory where each file is one table
- `t` for TAR archive (bigger than custom format)
- `-h`/`--host` Specifies the host name of the machine on which the server is running
- `-W`/`--password` Force `pg_dump` to prompt for a password before connecting to a database

restore backup:

```
   pg_restore -d database_name -U username -C backup.dump
```

Parameter `-C` should create database before importing data. If it doesn't work you can always create database eg. with command (as user `postgres` or other account that has rights to create databases) `createdb db_name -O owner`

**pg_dump/psql**

In case that you didn't specify the argument `-F` default plain text SQL format was used (or with `-F p`). Then you can't use `pg_restore`. You can import data with `psql`.

backup:

```
pg_dump -U username -f backup.sql database_name
```

restore:

```
psql -d database_name -f backup.sql
```

Comment: I used the "psql -d database_name -f backup.sql" command to restore a database I dumped from dokku on DigitalOcean. Worked great.

Comment: while using psql if your user (for e.g. `postgres`) has a password set  then `-W` option should be used. For e.g. on Ubuntu without doing `su postgres` anywhere from terminal `$ psql -h localhost -U postgres -W -d DB_NAME < DB_BACKUP.sql` is the command which worked for me to restore my backup on my localhost. Note that `-h` option is needed.

Comment: @JiggneshhGohel As the manual says: `-W` option is never essential. `pg_dump` will automatically prompt for a password if the server demands password authentication. Also you can use `PGPASSWORD` env variable, if you're using plain-text passwords. `-h` is needed if the default `PGHOST` is not applicable. These options are common for many PostgreSQL utils, thus not essential to answer this question (it heavily depends on your setup).

Comment: @Tombart your 2nd option `pg_dump/psql` part is work for me. but 1st part `pg_dump/pg_restore` is not work for me for restore. Thank you.

Comment: @AnjanBiswas The first option is using compressed archive, which will need more CPUs  but the backup file will occupy less space on disk. You just need to choose appropriate compression e.g. `-Fc`

Answer (score 80):

POSTGRESQL 9.1.12

DUMP:

```
pg_dump -U user db_name > archive_name.sql
```

put the user password and press enter.

RESTORE:

```
psql -U user db_name < /directory/archive.sql
```

put the user password and press enter.

Comment: How i can capture restore log in file instead of printing on screen? please let me know  i have tries with >>,  2>> , but not working thanks.

Answer (score 45):

Below is my version of `pg_dump` which I use to restore the database:

```
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d my_new_database my_old_database.backup
```

or use `psql`:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 my_new_database < my_old_database.backup
```

where `-h` host, `-p` port, `-u` login username, `-d` name of database

Comment: Govind Singh, why did you edit my answer? your changes bring nothing new..

Comment: `my_new_database` should already exist when using `psql`, not?

Answer (score 42):

**Backup and restore with GZIP**

> For larger size database this is very good

backup

```
pg_dump -U user -d mydb | gzip > mydb.pgsql.gz
```

restore

```
gunzip -c mydb.pgsql.gz | psql dbname -U user
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/backup-dump.html

Comment: For ubuntu you could use:
`gunzip -c mydb.pgsql.gz | sudo -u postgres psql`
To get the permissions to operate on the database.
Also consider the `--clean` flag when dumping, that will wipe all existing data, might come in handy.

Comment: Working great and neat solution for me. Thank you!

Comment: for windows it is hard to configure all eg. gungip command ;)

Answer (score 32):

This worked for me:

```sh
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner --host=localhost --dbname=db_name --username=username latest.dump
```

Comment: Thanks, the `--no-owner` really helped me.

Answer (score 18):

```
Backup:  $ pg_dump -U {user-name} {source_db} -f {dumpfilename.sql}

Restore: $ psql -U {user-name} -d {desintation_db} -f {dumpfilename.sql}
```

Answer (score 11):

#### Backup & Restore

This is the combo I'm using to **backup**, drop, create and **restore** my database (on macOS and Linux):

```
sudo -u postgres pg_dump -Fc mydb > ./mydb.sql
sudo -u postgres dropdb mydb
sudo -u postgres createdb -O db_user mydb
sudo -u postgres pg_restore -d mydb < ./mydb.sql
```

#### Misc

- `-Fc` will compress the database ([**F**ormat **c**ustom](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/app-pgdump.html))
- List PostgreSQL users: `sudo -u postgres psql -c "\du+"`
- You may want to add **hostname** and **date** to `./mydb.sql`, then change it by:

  ```
  ./`hostname`_mydb_`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M"`.sql
  ```

Comment: good stuff @DevonDahon, 4 commands that are straight to the point & doesn't need the psql shell. I was able successfully user your answer but had a warning `pg_restore: [custom archiver] WARNING: ftell mismatch with expected position -- ftell used` on Ubuntu 18.04 with postgres 10.13 so I don't know what that's about...

Answer (score 10):

try this:

```
psql -U <username> -d <dbname> -f <filename>.sql
```

Restore DB psql from .sql file

Comment: psql -U <username> -d <dbname>  -f <filename>.sql

Answer (score 9):

**1. Open the Terminal.**

**2. Backup your database with following command**

your postgres bin  -> `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/`

your source database server -> `192.168.1.111`

your backup file location and name -> `/home/dinesh/db/mydb.backup`

your source db name -> `mydatabase`

```
/opt/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_dump --host '192.168.1.111' --port 5432 --username "postgres" --no-password  --format custom --blobs --file "/home/dinesh/db/mydb.backup" "mydatabase"
```

**3. Restore mydb.backup file into destination.**

your destination server -> `localhost`

your destination database name -> `mydatabase`

**Create database for restore the backup.**

```
/opt/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/psql -h 'localhost' -p 5432 -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE mydatabase"
```

**Restore the backup.**

```
/opt/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_restore --host 'localhost' --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "mydatabase" --no-password --clean "/home/dinesh/db/mydb.backup"
```

Answer (score 8):

If you create a backup using pg_dump you can easily restore it in the following way:

1. Open command line window
2. Go to Postgres bin folder. For example:  `cd "C:\ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin"`
3. Enter the command to restore your database.  `For example: psql.exe -U postgres -d YourDatabase -f D:\Backup\.sql`
4. Type password for your postgres user
5. Check the restore process

Answer (score 8):

I didnt see here mentions about dump file extension (*.dump).

This solution worked for me:

I got a dump file and needed to recover it.

First I tried to do this with `pg_restore` and got:

```
pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.
```

I did it with `psql` and worked well:

```
psql -U myUser -d myDataBase < path_to_the_file/file.dump
```

Answer (score 8):

To restore a dump file

```
psql -d [Dbname] -U [UserName] -p 5432 < [FileLocation]
```

To restore a .SQL file

```
pg_restore -U [Username] -d [Dbname] -1 [FileLocation]
```

If you get user authentication errors, go to the file pg_hba.conf which is in PSQL/data folder in your program files, and change the "METHOD" to "Trust".
Restart you psql serive in windows services(Win + R --> services.msc).

Answer (score 8):

If you are using docker, this answer may be helpful.

1. Start the container

   ```
   docker start <postgres_container_id>
   ```
2. Access bash inside container

   ```
   docker exec -it <postgres_container_id> bash
   ```
3. Copy the `.tar` backup file to docker container (In another window)

   ```
   docker cp postgres_dump.tar <postgres_container_id>:/
   ```
4. Restore the backup

   ```
   pg_restore -c -U <postgres-user> -d <database-name>  -v "postgres_dump.tar" -W
   ```
5. Enter password

Answer (score 7):

1) Open psql terminal.

2) Unzip/ untar the dump file.

3) Create an empty database.

4) use the following command to restore the .dump file

```
<database_name>-# \i <path_to_.dump_file>
```

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U <username> -d <dbname> -1 <filename>
```

Answer (score 5):

Restoring a postgres backup file depends on how did you take the backup in the first place.

If you used pg_dump with -F c or -F d you need to use pg_restore otherwise you can just use

> psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres < backupfile

[9 ways to backup and restore postgres databases](http://www.brownfort.com/2014/10/backup-restore-postgresql/)

Comment: Do you realize that you missed the database name part and it will complain about destination database doesn't exist?

Answer (score 5):

## The shortest way with no password prompt

```
psql "postgresql://<db_user>:<db_pass>@<ip>:<port>/<db_name>" < "backup.sql"
```

## If you are using Windows OS

```
psql.exe "postgresql://<db_user>:<db_pass>@<ip>:<port>/<db_name>" < "backup.sql"
```

Answer (score 4):

As below link said, you can use psql command for restoring the dump file:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/backup.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE

```
psql dbname < infile
```

if you need to set username just add the username after the command like:

```
psql dbname < infile username
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the necropost, but these solutions did not work for me. I'm on postgres 10. On Linux:

1. I had to change directory to my pg_hba.conf.
2. I had to edit the file to change method from peer to md5 as stated [here](https://gist.github.com/AtulKsol/4470d377b448e56468baef85af7fd614)
3. Restart the service: `service postgresql-10 restart`
4. Change directory to where my backup.sql was located and execute:
   `psql postgres -d database_name -1 -f backup.sql`

   -database_name is the name of my database

   -backup.sql is the name of my .sql backup file.

Answer (score 3):

**Save and restore the exact same state with compressed dump**

Other answers gave all the key bits separately, but hopefully this will provide be the "just works save and restore to exact state" command pair.

Dump to file `mydb.psql`:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -U my_username -h localhost mydb -Fc -f mydb.psql
```

Restore:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_restore -U my_username -h localhost \
  --clean -d mydb -v mydb.psql
```

Some of the flags:

- `-Fc`: Format Compressed, as opposed to plaintext.

  `file tmp.psql` says:

  ```
  tmp.psql: PostgreSQL custom database dump - v1.14-0
  ```
- `--clean`: destroy the target DB before restoring it, thus returning to the exact same pristine state.

  Any data created after the dump will be lost.

`PGPASSWORD`, `-U` and `-h` can of course be modified depending on your login method, e.g. without `PGPASSWORD` you're prompted for a password, and none of those are needed if you set up peer auth locally.

Tested on Ubuntu 22.04, PostgreSQL 14.5.

Answer (score 2):

Try to see if the following commands can help you:

```
sudo su - yourdbuser
psql
\i yourbackupfile
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a backup SQL file then you can easily Restore it.
Just follow the instructions, given in the below

```
1. At first, create a database using pgAdmin or whatever you want (for example my_db is our created db name)
2. Now Open command line window
3. Go to Postgres bin folder. For example:  cd "C:\ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\pg10\bin"
4. Enter the following command to restore your database: psql.exe -U postgres -d my_db -f D:\Backup\backup_file_name.sql
```

Type password for your postgres user if needed and let Postgres to do its work. Then you can check the restore process.

Answer (score 2):

For example, you export the schema and data or only the schema of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` with [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) which must be used to import non-archive files as shown below. *`backup.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984733/postgresql-export-database-to-sql-file/77251389#77251389) explains how to export schema and data and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/77291122#77291122) explains how to import archive `backup.sql` into `orange` database and [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html) explains how to export and import databases:

```
pg_dump -U john apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -s apple > backup.sql
```

Or, you export only the data of the specific tables of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` with only `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below:

```
pg_dump -U john -a --column-inserts -t person -t animal apple > backup.sql
```

Then, you need to input a password after running the command above:

```
Password:
```

Now, you can import `backup.sql` into `orange` database of the user(role) `john` as shown below. *You have to create `orange` database before hand otherwise there is error and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641512/create-database-from-command-line-in-postgresql/77263012#77263012) explains how to create a database:

```
psql -U john -f backup.sql orange
```

Or:

```
psql -U john -d orange -f backup.sql
```

Or:

```
psql --username=john --file=backup.sql orange
```

Or:

```
psql --username john --file backup.sql orange
```

Or:

```
psql --username=john --dbname=orange --file=backup.sql
```

Or:

```
psql --username john --dbname orange --file backup.sql
```

Or, you can try these below which don't work on Windows:

```
psql -U john orange < backup.sql
```

```
psql -U john -d orange < backup.sql
```

```
psql --username=john --dbname=orange < backup.sql
```

```
psql --username john --dbname orange < backup.sql
```

Then, you need to input a password after running the command above:

```
Password for user john:
```

In addition, you can import `backup.sql` into `orange` database of the user(role) `john` without a password prompt by setting a password(e.g., `banana`) to [PGPASSWORD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html#id-1.7.3.22.3.4.6.1.1) as shown below:

```
PGPASSWORD=banana psql -U john -f backup.sql orange
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having authentication problems running pg_dump, so I moved my dump file

```
mv database_dump /tmp
```

into the temp directory and then ran

```
su -u postgres
cd /tmp
pg_restore database_dump
```

If you have a large database dump, you may just want to create another directory where your current user and the postgres user can access and putting the database dump file into that.

Answer (score 1):

Backup==>

Option1: To take backup along  with password in cmd
     `1.PGPASSWORD="mypassword"  pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost --inserts mydb>mydb.sql`
Option2: To take backup without password in cmd
     `2. pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost --inserts mydb>mydb.sql`
Option3: To take backup as gzip(if database is huge)
    `3. pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost mydb --inserts | gzip >  mydb.gz`

Restore:
    `1. psql -h localhost -d mydb -U postgres -p 5432 < mydb.sql`

Answer (score 1):

## This solution only works for **Windows**.

First, ensure you have already added the postgres bin folder to the "Path" environment variable (in my case this folder is C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin).

Then, open the Windows command interpreter (cmd), go to the folder where you have the .sql file and execute this command:

**pg_restore -U userName -d database-1 backupfile.sql**

For example:

**pg_restore -U sam -d SamDataBase -1 SamDataBaseBackup.sql**

(It can ask you for the password of the user so ensure to type it correctly and then click enter)

Pura vida!

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a new database named `mydb`, To restore a .sql dump to that database with psql,

```
psql --file=dump.sql --username=postgres --host=localhost --port=5432 mydb
```

the password will be prompted by psql

The connection options are

```
  -h, --host=HOSTNAME      database server host or socket directory (default: "/var/run/postgresql")
  -p, --port=PORT          database server port (default: "5432")
  -U, --username=USERNAME  database user name (default: "xyz")
  -w, --no-password        never prompt for password
  -W, --password           force password prompt (should happen automatically)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this command it will work

> psql -U postgres -W -d Test2 < E:\SampleProject\samplebackup.sql

Answer (score 1):

For example, you export and archive the schema and data or only the schema of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` with `-Fc` or `-Ft` as shown below. *`backup.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984733/postgresql-export-database-to-sql-file/77281946#77281946) explains how to export and archive a database with `-Fc` or `-Ft` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/77275771#77275771) explains how to import `backup.sql` into `orange` database and [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html) explains how to export and import databases:

```
pg_dump -U john -Fc apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -Ft apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -s -Fc apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -s -Ft apple > backup.sql
```

Or, you export and archive(`-Fc` or `-Ft`) only the data of the specific tables of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` with only `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below:

```
pg_dump -U john -Fc -a --column-inserts -t person -t animal apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -Ft -a --column-inserts -t person -t animal apple > backup.sql
```

Then, you need to input a password after running the command above:

```
Password:
```

Now, you can import archive `backup.sql` into `orange` database of the user(role) `john` with [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) which must be used to import archive files as shown below. *You have to create `orange` database before hand otherwise there is error and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641512/create-database-from-command-line-in-postgresql/77263012#77263012) explains how to create a database:

```
pg_restore -U john -d orange < backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_restore --username=john --dbname=orange < backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_restore --username john --dbname orange < backup.sql
```

Then, you need to input a password after running the command above:

```
Password for user john:
```

In addition, you can import `backup.sql` into `orange` database of the user(role) `john` without a password prompt by setting a password(e.g., `banana`) to [PGPASSWORD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html#id-1.7.3.22.3.4.6.1.1) as shown below:

```
PGPASSWORD=banana pg_restore -U john -d orange < backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to backup your data or restore data from a backup, you can run the following commands:

1. To create backup of your data, go to your postgres \bin\ directory like `C:\programfiles\postgres\10\bin\` and then type the following command:

   ```
   pg_dump -FC -U ngb -d ngb -p 5432 >C:\BACK_UP\ngb.090718_after_readUpload.backup
   ```
2. To restore data from a backup, go to your postgres \bin\ directory like `C:\programfiles\postgres\10\bin\` and then type below command:

   ```
   C:\programFiles\postgres\10\bin> pg_restore -Fc -U ngb -d ngb -p 5432 <C:\ngb.130918.backup
   ```

   Please make sure that the backup file exists.

Answer (score -2):

Follow these 3 steps :

> 1. start postgres server - `sudo systemctl start postgresql`
> 2. enable same - `sudo systemctl enable postgresql`
> 3. restore command - `pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d old_db`

*assuming that the dump is there in the same directory*

**Links** :

> https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-restore-database
> https://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432

Answer (score -5):

See below example its working

**C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin\pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username "postgres" --dbname "newDatabase" --no-password  --verbose**

"**C:\Users\Yogesh\Downloads\new Download\DB.backup**"