# Using `pg_dump` to only get insert statements from one table within database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-insert, pg-dump

I'm looking for a way to get all rows as `INSERT` statements from one specific table within a database using `pg_dump` in PostgreSQL.

E.g., I have table A and all rows in table A I need as `INSERT` statements, it should also dump those statements to a file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 353, accepted):

if version < 8.4.0

```
pg_dump -D -t <table> <database>
```

Add `-a` before the `-t` if you only want the INSERTs, without the CREATE TABLE etc to set up the table in the first place.

version >= 8.4.0

```
pg_dump --column-inserts --data-only --table=<table> <database>
```

Comment: The -d and -D options were removed from PostgreSQL 8.4 (see 8.4.0 release notes).  You must now use the "long" names: pg_dump --column-inserts --data-only --table=<table> <database>

Comment: The `-d`, `-a`, and `-t` short versions are still present, though. Checked with PG11.

Comment: `--inserts` is another option; it restores slightly faster but can't tolerate column order changes

Comment: You can check postgres version by running the query `SELECT version();`

Answer (score 60):

If you want to DUMP your inserts into an **.sql** file:

1. `cd` to the location where you want the `.sql` file to be located
2. **Run the following command:** `pg_dump --column-inserts --data-only --table=<table> <database> > my_dump.sql`

Note that the `> my_dump.sql` part of this command will put everything into an .sql file named **my_dump**

Answer (score 9):

just in case you are using a remote access and want to dump all database data, you can use:

`pg_dump -a -h your_host -U your_user -W -Fc your_database > DATA.dump`

it will create a dump with all database data and use

`pg_restore -a -h your_host -U your_user -W -Fc your_database < DATA.dump`

to insert the same data in your data base considering you have the same structure

Comment: For pg_restore, I had to add a -d for database: -d your_database < mydump.dump

Answer (score 3):

Put into a script I like something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace # remove me after debug
TABLE=some_table_name
DB_NAME=prod_database

BASE_DIR=/var/backups/someDir
LOCATION="${BASE_DIR}/myApp_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)"
FNAME="${LOCATION}_${DB_NAME}_${TABLE}.sql"

# Create backups directory if not exists
if [[ ! -e $BASE_DIR ]];then
       mkdir $BASE_DIR
       chown -R postgres:postgres $BASE_DIR
fi

sudo -H -u postgres pg_dump --column-inserts --data-only --table=$TABLE $DB_NAME > $FNAME
sudo gzip $FNAME
```

Answer (score 3):

for postgres 12, this worked for me:

```
pg_dump -d <database> -t <table> > DATA.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can export only the data of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984733/postgresql-export-database-to-sql-file/77251389#77251389) explains how to export both schema and data:

```
pg_dump -U john -a apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john --data-only apple > backup.sql
```

And, you can export only the data of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` with only `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below:

```
pg_dump -U john -a --column-inserts apple > backup.sql
```

And, you can export only the data of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` with only `INSERT` statement which doesn't have column names as shown below:

```
pg_dump -U john -a --inserts apple > backup.sql
```

And, you can export only the data of the specific tables `person` and `animal` of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` with only `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below. *Specifying multiple tables are available in one command:

```
pg_dump -U john -a --column-inserts -t person -t animal apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -a --column-inserts --table=person --table=animal apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -a --column-inserts --table person --table animal apple > backup.sql
```

Lastly for example, you export only the data of the specific tables `person` and `animal` of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` with only `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below:

```
pg_dump -U john -a --column-inserts -t person -t animal apple > backup.sql
```

Then, you can import `backup.sql` to `orange` database of the user(role) `john` with [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) which must be used to import non-archive files as shown below. *You have to create `orange` database and the schema otherwise there is error and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641512/create-database-from-command-line-in-postgresql/77263012#77263012) explains how to create a database and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/77275771#77275771) explains how to import schema and data:

```
psql -U john -f backup.sql orange
```

And, for example, you export and archive(`-Fc`) only the data of the specific tables `person` and `animal` of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` with only `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984733/postgresql-export-database-to-sql-file/77281946#77281946) explains how to export and archive a database:

```
pg_dump -U john -Fc -a --column-inserts -t person -t animal apple > backup.sql
```

Then, you can import archive `backup.sql` to `orange` database of the user(role) `john` with [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) which must be used to import archive files as shown below. *You have to create `orange` database and the schema otherwise there is error and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641512/create-database-from-command-line-in-postgresql/77263012#77263012) explains how to create a database and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/77291122#77291122) explains how to import archive files:

```
pg_restore -U john -d orange < backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the data set as insert commands without root user - using different user

pg_dump -U  -a  --column-inserts --data-only > backup.sql

data will be backed up into a backup.sql file

Comment: Hi Isuru.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  I'm interested in how this answer adds to the understanding for the question?  This might be better as a comment, because I don't see the question asking about how to dump the insert statements without root user.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).