# PostgreSQL. Generate create database statement for an existing databse

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

[How to generate the "create table" sql statement for an existing table in postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593803/how-to-generate-the-create-table-sql-statement-for-an-existing-table-in-postgr)
Here is explained how to generate such script for one table, but how to do the same for whole database?

Comment: are you trying to export the schema? if so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486241/how-can-i-export-the-schema-of-a-database-in-postgresql

Comment: @FuzzyTree thanks, your comment helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I need to extract the script that creates the database and all tables in it.

`pgdump -s databasename` does this

`pgdump -s databasename | awk 'RS="";/TABLE[^;]*;/'` allows extract statements of table creating/altering. Unfortunately I don't understand `awk` syntax.