# PostgreSQL export only the schema structure

Tags: database, postgresql, export

I have a Database which has multiple schema, I need to export one of those schema structure to an sql file without the data. Is this possible, if so What command should I use?

When I use this command, I get the data as well, but I have a lot of data which makes the server run out of space for this.

```
--host xx --port xx --username "xx" --password  --format plain --verbose --file "sample.sql" --schema "sample" "main"
```

I need the structure to restore it in another location. Where I do not need the data but only the structure

I'm quite new to this area, thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I export the schema of a database in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486241/how-can-i-export-the-schema-of-a-database-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use can use pg_dump with the option -s. Follow the link [pg_dump help](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html)

To extract the schema for a single database, use

```
pg_dump -s <schema_name>
```