# Is there a way to get all inserted data as INSERT statements from tables on postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a database in which I scraped a certain website and got all the classes for a specific year; so all the insert statements are automated. I was told by a professor that there's a way to export all that data as INSERT statements. Is that true? If so how do I go about that?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857989/using-pg-dump-to-only-get-insert-statements-from-one-table-within-database

Comment: Look for documentation on `pgdump`

Comment: yeah but the pg_dump command isn't recognized in my pgAdmin...For some odd reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on a table and select "backup". The popup will show various options, including "Format", select "plain" and you get plain SQL. Then you can navigate to "Dump options #2"and check the "Use Insert commands"

Answer (score 6):

In pgAdmin, select the `Backup` option on a database/schema/table, then check the `Insert commands` checkbox in the dialogue.

Comment: I'm not seeing any checkbox that says Insert commands. And when I try to back it up as is, I get a collection of strange characters...

Comment: You were right, but I have to put the format to "Plain" and there is no "Insert commands" option, I believe it is "Use Insert Commands"