# duplicate a postgresql database without deleting the destination one

Tags: postgresql

good morning

I can't duplicate a postgresql database from prod to my preprod database.

my prod and preprod databases are managed at Scaleway.

I have already made this system on MySql and it's very simple. we drop the tables and it's good.
with postgresql it is more complicated.

on the internet, we find solutions but each time, we say to delete the complete database to recreate. I can't do it because my database is managed.

I tried to do it with a pg_dump --clean --if-exist ....
but it does not work.

do you have a bright idea?

Thanks

Comment: "does not work" isn't a useful description of your problem is it? What exactly goes wrong and can you reproduce it with a local installation?

Comment: are the tables already exists in preprod? afaik `pg_dump` can be told to [make insert only backup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2858039) if needed.