# PostgreSQL: dump and restore

Tags: database, postgresql, restore, dump, database-dump

I use EMS SQL Manager for PostgreSQL and I need to dump difficult database(domains, 300+ stored procedures/functions, triggers, data, etc).
This tool cannot do it.

Please advice me good GUI tool for postgres.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can always just use the **command line** utility.
Dump the cluster:

```
pg_dumpall -p 5432 > /path/to/my/dump_file.sql
```

Dump a single database:

```
pg_dump -p 5432 mydb > /path/to/my/mydb_dump.sql
```

Dump the schema only:

```
pg_dump -p 5432 mydb -s > /path/to/my/mydb_dump_schema.sql
```

[More in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/reference-client.html)

If you want to restore to an empty database, you might want to run *before* restoring:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
```

The `--clean` option for `pg_dump` is not needed in this case.

Comment: Running the single database dump command and I get "database /path/to/my/mydb_dump.sql does not exist"

Comment: @multigoodverse: You seem to have omitted the database name. `mydb` in the example.

Answer (score 6):

Backup your database no tool needed.we can do with terminal

All commands should be run as the postgres user.

```
 sudo su - postgres
```

Backup a single database

```
pg_dump db_name > db_backup.sql
```

Restore a single database

```
psql db_name < db_backup.sql
```

Backup an entire postgres database cluster

```
pg_dumpall > cluster_backup.sql
```

Restore an entire postgres database cluster

```
psql -f cluster_backup.sql postgres
```

Refer this source for more commands [backup commands](http://www.rubytreesoftware.com/resources/basic-postgresql-backup-and-restore)

Answer (score 3):

[pgAdmin3](http://www.pgadmin.org/) will do the trick, it has pg_dump and pg_restore included in the installer.

Comment: Thanks. I don't like this tool for its ascetic interface. BTW pg_dump has no dump options like 'delete ... if ... exists', it has only '-c' option

Comment: That's a matter of taste. And why would pg_dump have to delete something? And yes, pg_dump is the only way to make a proper dump from the database that I know of, all GUI tools use this piece of software in the background.

Comment: Also, what's wrong with the `--clean` option? If the object to be deleted does not exist while restoring, nothing breaks.

Comment: If the object to be deleted does not exist, the script stop running with an error 'ERROR:  relation "public.t_payment" does not exist' on line 'ALTER TABLE ONLY public.t_payment DROP CONSTRAINT fk_user_payer;'

Comment: There are many ways to dump a PostgreSQL database, depending on your needs.  We primarily use PITR-style backups. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/backup.html

Answer (score 3):

if you use md5 authentication technique and want to use a specific user to get db dump, you can do

```
$ pg_dump -U username -p 5432 dbname > filename-to-backup-to.sql
```

To avoid credential and username issues while restoring, you can use `--no-owner` flag

```
$ pg_dump --no-owner -U username -p 5432 dbname > filename-to-backup-to.sql
```

To restore the backup use below command

```
$ psql -U username -d dbname -f filename-to-backup-to.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

pg_dump -U uguryilmaz modaltrans_dev > backup.sql

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can export everything such as all databases, users(roles), etc to `backup.sql` with  [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html) as shown below. *`backup.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and you better use any superusers(e.g., `postgres`) to do it smoothly without permission errors and `pg_dumpall` can output SQL in only plain text format rather than custom format or tar format and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984733/postgresql-export-database-to-sql-file/77251389#77251389) explains how to export schema and data with [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) and [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-ALL) explains how to export and import everything with `pg_dumpall`:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres -f backup.sql
```

Or, you can export everything except the data of all databases to `backup.sql` as shown below:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres -s > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres --schema-only > backup.sql
```

Or, you can export everything except the schema of all databases to `backup.sql` with only `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres -a --column-inserts > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres --data-only --column-inserts > backup.sql
```

Then, you will need to input multiple passwords after running the command above:

```
Password: 
Password: 
Password:
...
```

Then, you can import `backup.sql`(everything) into your PostgreSQL as shown below.

```
psql -U postgres -f backup.sql
```

Or, you can try this below which doesn't work on Windows:

```
psql -U postgres < backup.sql
```

Or, you can import `backup.sql`(everything) into your PostgreSQL with `\i` after login with the user(role) `postgres` as shown below:

```
psql -U postgres
postgres=# \i backup.sql
```

Or, you can import `backup.sql` into multiple databases one by one as shown below. *You have to create each database (and the schema to import only data) before hand otherwise there is error and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641512/create-database-from-command-line-in-postgresql/77263012#77263012) explains how to create a database and you must use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) to import SQL in plain text format rather than [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) which can import SQL in custom format or tar format and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/77275771#77275771) explains how to import `backup.sql` into `orange` database:

```
psql -U postgres -f backup.sql orange
psql -U postgres -f backup.sql lemon
psql -U postgres -f backup.sql peach
...
```

In addition, you can export all databases to `backup.sql` without multiple password prompts by setting a password(e.g., `banana`) to [PGPASSWORD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html#id-1.7.3.22.3.4.6.1.1) as shown below:

```
PGPASSWORD=banana pg_dumpall -U postgres > backup.sql
```

And, you can export all databases excluding `orange` and `*apple*` databases to `backup.sql` as shown below. *Multiple `--exclude-database` are available in one command:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres --exclude-database=orange --exclude-database=*apple* > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres --exclude-database orange --exclude-database *apple* > backup.sql
```