# Create database from command line in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, command-line, command, psql

I am trying to create a database from command line.
My OS is centos and postgres version is 10.9.

```
sudo -u postgres psql createdb test
Password for user test:
```

Why is it prompting me for the password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure postgresql for the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471571/how-to-configure-postgresql-for-the-first-time)

Answer (score 315, accepted):

Change the user to postgres :

```
su - postgres
```

Create User for Postgres (in the shell and *NOT* with psql)

```
$ createuser testuser
```

Create Database (same)

```
$ createdb testdb
```

Acces the postgres Shell

```
psql ( enter the password for postgressql)
```

Provide the privileges to the postgres user

```
$ alter user testuser with encrypted password 'qwerty';
$ grant all privileges on database testdb to testuser;
```

Comment: Important: createuser and createdb are run in the shell and *NOT* with psql.

Comment: But if run with psql, the correct commands are: ```create user testuser; create database testdb;```

Comment: If the name of user is 'user', Can it be run as "$ alter user user with encrypted password 'qwerty';"

Answer (score 127):

Try:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c 'create database test;'
```

Comment: do not forget to grant permissions as well:
`sudo -u postgres psql -c 'grant all privileges on database test to username;'`

Comment: On mac, it's just `psql -c 'create database test;'`

Comment: @JoshuaSwain That could be done if you have a postgresql user with the same name with your shell user with the privilege to create new database.

Answer (score 74):

`createdb` is a command line utility which you can run from bash and not from psql. To create a database from psql, use the create database statement like so:

```
create database [databasename];
```

Note: be sure to always end your SQL statements with `;`

Comment: Plus one for the hint about ending with `;`

Comment: Just wanted to comment that Postgres makes UPPERCASE to lower. So `CREATE DATABASE FOO` would actually create database named `foo`. It took
 me like 5 minutes to figure out why "database doesn't exists".

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111996/why-postgresql-does-not-like-uppercase-table-names

Answer (score 52):

As some of the answers point out, `createdb` is a command line utility that could be used to create database.

Assuming you have a user named `dbuser`, the following command could be used to create a database and provide access to `dbuser`:

```
createdb -h localhost -p 5432 -U dbuser testdb
```

Replace `localhost` with your correct DB host name, `5432` with correct DB port, and `testdb` with the database name you want to create.

Now `psql` could be used to connect to this newly created database:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U dbuser -d testdb
```

Tested with `createdb` and `psql` versions `9.4.15`.

Comment: This was the right way to create a database on an instance I can't ssh to. All the attempts to run "CREATE DB" as -c param for remote psql utility assumed the existence of a database named like the user

Comment: This was the way that worked for me when using docker and wanting to add a 2nd database to the one that was added as part of the init of the postgres image:
`docker exec -it postgres-container sh -c "createdb -h YOUR_HOST -p YOUR_PORT -U YOUR_USER YOUR_DATABASE"`

Answer (score 24):

As the default configuration of Postgres, a user called **postgres** is made and the user **postgres** has full super admin access to entire PostgreSQL instance running on your OS.

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

The above command gets you the psql command line interface in admin mode.

**Creating user**

```
sudo -u postgres createuser <username>
```

**Creating Database**

```
 sudo -u postgres createdb <dbname>
```

***NOTE: < > are not to be used while writing command, they are used just to signify the variables***

Answer (score 10):

**[PostgreSQL Create Database](https://orahow.com/postgresql-create-database/) - Steps to create database in Postgres.**

1. **Login to server using postgres user.**

   ```
   su - postgres
   ```
2. **Connect to postgresql database.**

```
bash-4.1$ psql
psql (12.1)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=#
```

3. **Execute below command to create database.**

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

**Check for detailed information below:**
https://orahow.com/postgresql-create-database/

Comment: Please notice the `;` character in the end of the line! It is important that you type it!
Verify that the db was indeed created by using `\l`

Answer (score 4):

With a single command line:

```
su -c "createuser dbuser;createdb -h localhost -p 5432 -E UTF8 -O dbuser dbname;" - postgres
```

Answer (score 3):

```
PGPORT=5432
PGHOST="my.database.domain.com"
PGUSER="postgres"
PGDB="mydb"
createdb -h $PGHOST -p $PGPORT -U $PGUSER $PGDB
```

Comment: If you change 'PGDB' to 'PGDATABASE' and export them (or prefix them to the command), then you don't need to pass these to the command, it'll read them from the environment.

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty simple but sometimes I find the answers tricky.

[For windows users]

Open Windows cmd

- `psql -U <username>`
- Once connected to psql, enter the following command to create a new database:
   `CREATE DATABASE <database_name>;`
- To verify that the database has been created, you can run the `\l` command to list all available databases. Your new database should be listed in the output.
  ------[Additional]------
- You can now connect to the new database using the \c command followed by the database name, like this: 
   `\c <database_name>`
- You can now run SQL commands on the new database to create tables, insert data, and so on. 
  Note: Make sure to replace `<username>`, `<database_name>` with your actual Postgres username and database name.

Comment: notice not to forget the ; at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pgAdmin:

In query editor you can try like this :

```
CREATE DATABASE <databasename>
    WITH 
    OWNER = <dbowner>
    ENCODING = <encoding>
    CONNECTION LIMIT = <numberofsimulaneousconnections>;
```

an example snippet :

```
CREATE DATABASE twitterdb
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, first, you can create the user(role) `john` with the password `banana` as shown below. *By default, PostgreSQL needs a password so you should set `PASSWORD` and you can omit `WITH` which is optional and you must use `''` for `PASSWORD` instead of `""` otherwise there is error:

```sql
CREATE ROLE john WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'banana';
```

Then, you can create `apple` database with the owner `john` as shown below. *If you omit `OWNER`, the current user(role) is the database owner:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE apple OWNER john;
```

In addition, if you want to drop the user(role) `john`, you need to remove the owner `john` from `apple` database by replacing it with other (e.g., `david`), then drop the user(role) `john` as shown below otherwise there is error. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023583/how-to-quickly-drop-a-user-with-existing-privileges/77299812#77299812) explains how to drop a user(role) more properly:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE apple OWNER TO david;
DROP ROLE john;
```

Or:

```sql
REASSIGN OWNED BY john TO david;  
DROP ROLE john;
```

In addition again, you can drop the database as shown below:

```sql
DROP DATABASE apple;
```