# Issue with Invalid User logging in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

When I write `createdb mydb` in the bash terminal. I write the password, but I am getting an error for a user "amodhakal". I have not set up that user, so I was wondering how I can change that user to "postgres" so I can use `createdb mydb`. Thank You for helping. If more clarification is needed, just let me know!

```
$ createdb mydb
Password: 
Password: 
createdb: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "amodhakal"
```

When I type psql, I get password for user amodhakal. Like I said, that user doesn't exist so I need to delete that user, and change it to "postgres"

```
psql
Password for user amodhakal:
```

Comment: Like all postgres utility scripts, [`createdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html) takes a `-U` connection parameter option.

Comment: I want to be where I can just use createdb without -U like how the invalid user "amodhakal" is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create database from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641512/create-database-from-command-line)

Comment: That's just not how `createdb` works. It uses the current shell user (OS account) name if you don't specify a username explicitly.

Comment: @bergi is there a way to change that funcitonality from using OS account explicitly to using postgres. I did use ```su - postgres``` from the post you said, but it is saying su: command not found

Comment: So you're not on a unixoid OS that has [`su`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix))? But sure, the way change this functionality and explicitly use the postgres user is `createdb -U postgres …`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: [createdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html) is a `libpg` based client so you can use environment variables as shown in the **Environment** section of the `createdb` link to set the connection parameters. In your case `PGUSER`. Though this will become the 'default' user for all `libpq` based clients that are the same environment, unless overridden at the command line.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[createdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html) is a `libpq` based client so you can use environment variables as shown in the **Environment** section of the createdb link to set the connection parameters. In your case `PGUSER`. Though this will become the 'default' user for all `libpq` based clients that are the same environment, unless overridden at the command line. For all the `libpq` environment variables available see [libpq env](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)