# PostgreSQL: Export database to .sql file

Tags: database, postgresql, command, export, postgresql-9.1

I want to export my database as a `.sql` file.
Can someone help me? The solutions I have found don't work.
A detailed description please.
On Windows 7.

Comment: what OS postgres runs at?

Comment: Windows 7 is the OS

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html

Answer (score 127, accepted):

[pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) defaults to plain SQL export. both data and structure.

open [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window) and 
run `pg_dump -U username -h localhost databasename >> sqlfile.sql`

Above command is preferable as most of the times there will be an error which will be something like  - `...FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user ...`

Comment: go to a file with the cmd? and then type these?

Comment: what OS u use? Windows? osX? Linux? BSD?

Comment: On windows 7 and postgres 1.22.1

Comment: This is dumping only structures. What if I need data as wee?

Comment: it dumps only structures with `--schema-only` or `-s` - otherwise it does both

Comment: Note that you'll run this command on the CLI without logging in with the 'psql' command.

You can also add the port number like so:

`pg_dump -U username -h localhost -p 5433 dbName >> dumpFile.sql`

The file will be created in your 'home' folder using the command above but you can specify the location you want.

Comment: Hi, you export this PostgreSQL db to .sql file. Is there a way to open this exported .sql file in python?

Answer (score 20):

In windows, first, make sure the path is added in environment variables PATH

`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin`

After a successful path adding restart cmd and type command

`pg_dump -U username -p portnumber -d dbname -W -f location`

> this command will export both schema and data

for only schema use `-s` in place of `-W`
and for only data use `-a`.

replace each variable like username, portnumber, dbname and location according to your situation
 **everything is case sensitive, make sure you insert everything correctly,**
and to import

`psql -h hostname -p port_number -U username -f your_file.sql databasename`

make sure your db is created or creation query is present in .sql file

**Documentation:** https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

Comment: Hi, you export this PostgreSQL db to .sql file. Is there a way to open this exported .sql file in python?

Answer (score 7):

Go to your command line and run

```
pg_dump -U userName -h localhost -d databaseName > ~/Desktop/cmsdump.sql
```

Comment: this worked on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Hi, you export this PostgreSQL db to .sql file. Is there a way to open this exported .sql file in python?

Comment: `with open('exported_file_name.sql', 'r') as file:
    # Read the contents of the file
    sql_script = file.read()

# Print the contents to verify
print(sql_script)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows open cmd and run the folloing command, edit the details like user and database

```
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -d statepos > C:\Users\ston\Desktop\statepos.sql
```

Comment: Hi, you export this PostgreSQL db to .sql file. Is there a way to open this exported .sql file in python?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can export the schema and data of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` as shown below. *`backup.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and you can also use `-Fp` explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984733/postgresql-export-database-to-sql-file/77281946#77281946) of how to export and archive a database with `-Fc` and `-Ft` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337095/postgresql-dump-and-restore/77318116#77318116) explains how to export and import all databases and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/77275771#77275771) explains how to import `backup.sql` into `orange` database and [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html) explains how to export and import databases:

```
pg_dump -U john apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -d apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump --username=john --dbname=apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump --username john --dbname apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -f backup.sql apple
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -d apple -f backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump --username=john --file=backup.sql apple
```

Or:

```
pg_dump --username john --file backup.sql apple
```

Or:

```
pg_dump --username=john --dbname=apple --file=backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump --username john --dbname apple --file backup.sql
```

Then, you need to input a password after running the command above:

```
Password:
```

In addition, you can export the schema and data of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` without a password prompt by setting a password(e.g., `banana`) to [PGPASSWORD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html#id-1.7.3.22.3.4.6.1.1) as shown below:

```
PGPASSWORD=banana pg_dump -U john apple > backup.sql
```

And, you can export only the schema of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` with `-s` or `--schema-only` as shown below:

```
pg_dump -U john -s apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john --schema-only apple > backup.sql
```

Or, you can export only the data of the specific tables `person` and `animal` of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` with only `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below. *Specifying multiple tables are available in one command and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857989/using-pg-dump-to-only-get-insert-statements-from-one-table-within-database/77291764#77291764) explains how to export only data more:

```
pg_dump -U john -a --column-inserts -t person -t animal apple > backup.sql
```

Then, you need to input a password after running the command above:

```
Password:
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can export and archive the schema and data of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` with e.g. `-Fc`, `-Ft`, `--format=c` and `--format t`  as shown below. *`backup.sql` is created if it doesn't exist and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984733/postgresql-export-database-to-sql-file/77251389#77251389) explains how to export schema and data and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/77291122#77291122) explains how to import archive `backup.sql` into `orange` database and [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html) explains how to export and import databases:

```
pg_dump -U john -Fc apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -Ft -d apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump --username=john --format=c --dbname=apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump --username john --format t --dbname apple > backup.sql
```

- `c` means **custom** which outputs a custom-format archive suitable for input into `pg_restore`. *`pg_restore` must be used to import the file.
- `t` means **tar** which outputs a tar-format archive suitable for input into `pg_restore`. *`pg_restore` must be used to import the file.
- `d` means **directory** which outputs a directory-format archive suitable for input into pg_restore. *`pg_restore` must be used to import the file but it doesn't work properly giving error.
- `p` means **plain** which outputs a plain-text SQL script file (the default). *`psql` must be used to import the file.

*`pg_restore` is to import archive files created with `c`, `t` and `d` while `psql` is to import non-archive files created with `p` (default) and [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) explains it more:

Then, you need to input a password after running the command above:

```
Password:
```

In addition, you can export and archive the schema and data of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` without a password prompt by setting a password(e.g., `banana`) to [PGPASSWORD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html#id-1.7.3.22.3.4.6.1.1) as shown below:

```
PGPASSWORD=banana pg_dump -U john -Fc apple > backup.sql
```

And, you can export and archive only the schema of `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` as shown below:

```
pg_dump -U john -s -Fc apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john --schema-only -Fc apple > backup.sql
```

Or, you can export and archive only the data of the specific tables `apple` database of the user(role) `john` to `backup.sql` only `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below:

```
pg_dump -U john -Fc -a --column-inserts -t person -t animal apple > backup.sql
```

Then, you need to input a password after running the command above:

```
Password:
```