# The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump. Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database

Tags: database, postgresql, google-app-engine, gcloud, custom-formatting

I've encountered following error message when I'm trying to import a postgres dump file to Google Cloud SQL.

> The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump. Use the pg_restore
> command-line client to restore this dump to a database. This may take
> a few minutes. While this operation is running, you may continue to
> view information about the instance.

Please let me know how to import a postgres dump file (which is hosted on Google Cloud Storage) to Google Cloud SQL?

Comment: did you try using `pg_restore`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun my problem is I don't know how to put that dump file in Google Cloud Platform Console.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/creating-sqldump-csv states you can't use custom format for google cloud sql

Comment: @VaoTsun i know. again, the problem is when I run that command `pg_restore -d my_new_database temp.sql` where to put temp.sql in google cloud storage and how to include like `s3://asdfafasfa` something like

Comment: but this is totally unrelated to the posts subject?.. Please post a different question then

Comment: nope, problem is already mention in detail though

Answer (score 8):

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/creating-sqldump-csv

> Important: you must ensure that your SQL dump file is created with the
>   following flags:
>
> - --no-owner Ownership change commands must not be included in the SQL dump file.
> - --format=plain Only plain SQL format is currently supported by Cloud SQL.

and from error you see I assume you used custom format, thus the import sql you prepared won't work (at least by documentation)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

> --format=format Selects the format of the output. format can be one of the following:
>
> **p plain** Output a plain-text SQL script file (the default).
>
> **c custom** Output a custom-format archive suitable for input into
>   pg_restore. Together with the directory output format, this is the
>   most flexible output format in that it allows manual selection and
>   reordering of archived items during restore. This format is also
>   compressed by default.

Comment: i know. again, the problem is when I run that command `pg_restore -d my_new_database temp.sql` where to put temp.sql in google cloud storage and how to include like `s3://asdfafasfa` something like

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump.
> Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database.

Because I exported and archived `apple` database to `backup.sql` in `-Fc`(custom format) with [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) as shown below:

```
pg_dump -U john -Fc apple > backup.sql
```

Then, I tried to import archive `backup.sql` to `orange` database with [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) which must be used to import non-archive files:

```
psql -U john -f backup.sql orange
```

So, I did it with [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) which must be used to import archive files, then I could solve the error. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984733/postgresql-export-database-to-sql-file/77281946#77281946) explains how to export and archive a database with `-Fc` and `-Ft` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/77291122#77291122) explains how to import a database:

```
pg_restore -U john -d orange < backup.sql
```