# How to read a .SQL file of 42GB in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I get a .sql file of 42GB from an open-data website of the french governement. According the metadata, this file is made for a PostgreSQL database.

My final aim is to read it in BigQuery which accept only CSV file.

I didn't find a simple solution to convert it in CSV because I don't even know how to read this file to have the list of the existing tables inside it.

Should I install PostgreSQL on local on my computer?
I'm concern d that the file will be too big for my computer

Should I use a Linux server to convert it?
Which command line?

Comment: If you're question is about BigQuery why have you tagged **four** *completely* different RDBMS products...?

Comment: So what about your question is *specially* about MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server *and* BigQuery? [Edit] your question to explain why knowledge of *all* those products is required to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Samuel, **PostgreSQL** lets  you export the whole database to an sql file with the command [pg_dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984733/postgresql-database-export-to-sql-file): `pg_dump -U username -h localhost databasename >> sqlfile.sql`

The main command inside this file is to create a table and to insert the data. You can run **GCP Cloud SQL** and import the sql file [there](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/import-export-dmp).

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki as it is a possible workaround of this use case. This will be for the benefit of the community that might encounter this question in the future.

Please feel free to edit this answer for additional information and if there are other possible workarounds/direct solutions for this use case.