# how to restore a postgresql database from a file?

Tags: postgresql

I have a open source application downloaded , and they ask to restore a postgresql db from a file
how to do ?

here is the file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4jjW_n_JyTGbjdranlTRUFuOEk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't have access to the file. What is in it? How was it created?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2732521/1216680