# Why does pg_restore return "options -d/--dbname and -f/--file cannot be used together"?

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

The following Windows batch script fails on the line with database restore:

```
@Echo off

set Path=C:\Program Files (x86)
set Backup_Path=C:\Program Files (x86) 

c:  
cd \  
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin  

@echo "Wait ..."  
setlocal
set PGPASSWORD=1234
psql.exe -U postgres -c "create database Mydata"  
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\pg_restore.exe" -h localhost -U postgres -d Mydata -f "Mydata.backup"

pause 
endlocal
```

The error is:

> pg_restore : -d / - dbname and -f / - file can not be used together
>   Try " pg_restore --help "

Comment: Remove the `-f` switch. It is not a switch for specifying input file as you might think.

Comment: Why do you use such an old version for a *new* install?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`-f` is the **output** filename, not the input file.

The input file does not have any parameter switch.

```
c:\>pg_restore --help
pg_restore restores a PostgreSQL database from an archive created by pg_dump.

Usage:
  pg_restore [OPTION]... [FILE]

General options:
  -d, --dbname=NAME        connect to database name
  -f, --file=FILENAME      output file name
  -F, --format=c|d|t       backup file format (should be automatic)
  -l, --list               print summarized TOC of the archive
  -v, --verbose            verbose mode
  -V, --version            output version information, then exit
  -?, --help               show this help, then exit
```

So you need to use:

```
pg_restore.exe -h localhost -U postgres -d Mydata "Mydata.backup"
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: Now my  setup installs  my software ,my database and makes a restore  :)