# Docker - How can run the psql command in the postgres container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I would like to use the psql in the postgres image in order to run some queries on the database.
But unfortunately when I attach to the postgres container, I got that error the psql command is not found...

For me a little bit it is a mystery how I can run postgre sql queries or commands in the container.

How run the psql command in the postgres container? (I am a new guy in Docker world)

I use Ubuntu as a host machine, and I did not install the postgres on the host machine, I use the postgres container instead.

```
docker-compose ps
        Name                       Command               State               Ports            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
yiialkalmi_app_1        /bin/bash                        Exit 0                               
yiialkalmi_nginx_1      nginx -g daemon off;             Up       443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp 
yiialkalmi_php_1        php-fpm                          Up       9000/tcp                    
yiialkalmi_postgres_1   /docker-entrypoint.sh postgres   Up       5432/tcp                    
yiialkalmi_redis_1      docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up       6379/tcp
```

Here the containers:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                         NAMES
315567db2dff        yiialkalmi_nginx    "nginx -g 'daemon off"   18 hours ago        Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp   yiialkalmi_nginx_1
53577722df71        yiialkalmi_php      "php-fpm"                18 hours ago        Up 3 hours          9000/tcp                      yiialkalmi_php_1
40e39bd0329a        postgres:latest     "/docker-entrypoint.s"   18 hours ago        Up 3 hours          5432/tcp                      yiialkalmi_postgres_1
5cc47477b72d        redis:latest        "docker-entrypoint.sh"   19 hours ago        Up 3 hours          6379/tcp                      yiialkalmi_redis_1
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
app:
image: ubuntu:16.04
volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html

nginx:
    build: ./docker/nginx/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - app
    volumes:
        - ./docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d

php:
    build: ./docker/php/
    expose:
        - 9000
    links:
        - postgres
        - redis
    volumes_from:
        - app

postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/postgres
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: project
        POSTGRES_USER: project
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: project

redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
        - 6379
```

Answer (score 259, accepted):

```
docker exec -it yiialkalmi_postgres_1 psql -U project -W project
```

Some explanation

- `docker exec -it`
  The command to run a command to a running container. The `it` flags open an interactive tty. Basically it will cause to attach to the terminal. If you wanted to open the bash terminal you can do this

`docker exec -it yiialkalmi_postgres_1 bash`

- `yiialkalmi_postgres_1` 
  The container name (you could use the container id instead, which in your case would be `40e39bd0329a` )
- `psql -U project -W project`
  The command to execute to the running container
- `U` user
- `W` Tell psql that the user needs to be prompted for the password at connection time. *This parameter is optional.* Without this parameter, there is an extra connection attempt which will usually find out that a password is needed, see the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html).
- `project` the database you want to connect to. There is no need for the `-d` parameter to mark it as the dbname when it is the first non-option argument, see the docs: `-d` "is equivalent to specifying dbname as the first non-option argument on the command line."

These are specified by you here

```
environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: project
    POSTGRES_USER: project
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: project
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works.
I tried with this always: `docker exect it 40e39bd0329a /bin/bash` and then in the container run the `psql` command, but it always gave me errors.

Comment: No need to run `/bin/bash` as it is already in the path. If you run `docker exec -it 40e39bd0329a bash` and then when you in the container's bash shell, you execute `psql -U project -W project project` it should work. If you execute only `psql` you should get an error about `role not found` which is postgres' way of informing you that the default user (in this case I think it's `root`) doesn't exist in postgres' specified users

Comment: To be exact you must be getting `psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist` where user that you are connecting as, to the container (`root@<SOMETHING>:/#`)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I'm trying to restore a database using that command but I'm not sure is is ok, any help?

docker exec avm_db_1 psql -U postgres < mydatabase.back

Comment: @joselo I haven't done this before, but I'm confident it's not that hard. Please open a new thread posting your question. That way more people will see your question. The comments are not a good place to ask a new question.

Comment: May need to use `docker exec -it yiialkalmi_postgres_1 sh -c "psql -U project -W project project"` instead.

Comment: `docker-compose exec postgres psql -U project -W project` works too if you have a running container (`docker-compose up postgres`).

Comment: How to set the hostname?

Comment: i get ```"could not connect to server: no such file or directory"``` seems to be looking in ```/var/run/postgresql/``` which does not exist

Comment: If its just one command, you could put it straight there as psql parameter `--command="CREATE extension whatever"`

Comment: After running the above command, I was getting
  `psql: warning: extra command-line argument "project" ignored`
  
  For me this worked, 
  `docker exec -it <container_id> psql -U <username> -W <database_name>`

Comment: Above command is what worked for me as well.

Comment: @KarthikRao Right, `-W` does not need a value after it. The first non-option parameter stands for the dbname, which is why the double project is just wrong. I am just editing this.

Comment: If you define `PGPASSWORD` environment variable (e.g. in `docker-compose.yml`), you won't need to type any password.

Answer (score 47):

This worked for me:

goto bash :

```
docker exec -it <container-name> bash
```

from bash :

```
psql -U <dataBaseUserName> <dataBaseName>
```

or just this one-liner :

```
docker exec -it  <container-name> psql -U <dataBaseUserName> <dataBaseName>
```

helps ?

Comment: This works! Why doesn't it need the password though? Doing the answer by @Alkis Kalogeis with -W "your password" confuses postgresql and it thinks the password i put in is the data base

Comment: @Sheng it doesn't need the password because pg_hba.conf trusts local connections, and when you run psql inside the container like this, it's a local connection.

Answer (score 29):

After the Postgres container is configured using docker, open the bash terminal using:

```sh
docker exec -it <containerID>(postgres container name / ID) bash
```

Switch to the Postgres user:

```sh
su - postgres
```

Then run:

```sh
psql
```

It will open the terminal access for the Postgres.

Answer (score 22):

If you need to restore the database in a container you can do this:

```
docker exec -i app_db_1 psql -U postgres < app_development.back
```

Don't forget to add `-i`.

:)

Answer (score 11):

You can enter inside the postgres container using docker-compose by typing the following

```
docker-compose exec postgres bash
```

knowing that **postgres** is the name of the service. Replace it with the name of the **Postgresql service** in you docker-compose file.

if you have many docker-compose files, you have to add the specific docker-compose.yml file you want to execute the command with. Use the following commnand instead.

```
docker-compose -f < specific docker-compose.yml> exec postgres bash
```

For example if you want to run the command with a docker-compose file called **local.yml**, here the command will be

```
docker-compose -f local.yml exec postgres bash
```

Then, use psql command and specify the database name with the -d flag and the username with the -U flag

```
psql -U <database username you want to connect with> -d <database name>
```

Baammm!!!!! you are in.

Answer (score 6):

If you have running "postgres" container:

```
docker run -it --rm --link postgres:postgres postgres:9.6 sh -c "exec psql -h \$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR -p \$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT -U postgres"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can enter the container with a terminal sh or bash by using,

> docker run -it <container id | name> <sh | bash>

if assume it is sh,

> psql -U postgres

will work

Answer (score 3):

Just fired up a local test, not sure if `-c` is what you were after from the cli.

```sh
docker run -it --rm --name psql-test-connection -e PGPASSWORD=1234 postgres psql -h kubernetes.docker.internal -U awx -c "\conninfo"

You are connected to database "awx" as user "awx" on host "kubernetes.docker.internal" (address "192.168.65.4") at port "5432".
```

Answer (score 3):

In many common setups, the PostgreSQL port is published out to the host.

```yaml
postgres:
  ports:
    - '12345:5432'
```

If this is the case, you don't need to do anything Docker-specific to connect to the database.  You can use the `psql` client directly on your host system pointing to the first `ports:` number.

```bash
psql -h localhost -p 12345 -U project
```

This approach only requires `psql` or another ordinary PostgreSQL client be installed on the host and that the database container be configured with `ports:` making it accessible from outside Docker.  (The `ports:` are not necessary for inter-container communication and a production-oriented setup could reasonably not have them.)  This does not require the ability to run `docker` commands and the attendant security concerns, and it can avoid multiple layers of additional command quoting from a `docker exec sh -c '...'` sequence.

Answer (score 2):

```
RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER docker WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'docker';" &&\
    createdb -O docker docker &&\
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Pleast take some time to read [answer]. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Without using an external terminal a person can run SQL commands within the container CLI.

`psql -d [database-name] -U [username] -W`

** Don't forget to replace [database-name] with your db-name & [username] with your actual username

Flags:

> ```
> -d : Specify the database name you want to connect
> -U : Specify the username as whom you want to connect
> -W : Prompt for the password
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need but trying to run queries automatically `when starting the server`.

I achieved it using another service with the same image only to run those queries:

```yaml
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg15
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_DB: "postgres"
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U postgres -d postgres
      interval: 3s
      timeout: 0s
      retries: 30

  database-start-scripts:
    container_name: database-start-scripts
    image: timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg15
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
    # Some seeding
    command:
      - 'bash'
      - '-c'
      - |
        PGPASSWORD=postgres psql -h hiphiphip-database -p 5432 -U postgres postgres  <<SQL
          CREATE USER my_user WITH PASSWORD 'my_password';
          ALTER USER my_user WITH SUPERUSER;
          CREATE DATABASE my_db WITH OWNER my_user;
        SQL
```

Hoping this may help!