# Docker & Postgres - Rename database & remove old one

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have my Gitlab CI running with Symfony, I have fixtures loaded and I want to load them in a *buffer* dabatase, and then to move them to the *real* database.

I've seen this thread: [Docker - How can run the psql command in the postgres container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099564/docker-how-can-run-the-psql-command-in-the-postgres-container), but I would like to have an automatic script which:

- delete my *real* database
- rename my *buffer* database to the real database's name

Is it possible using Docker & Gitlab CI to automate such commands? I am using `pg_dump` for now, but it's long an not easy to use, I just want to replace a DB with an other DB.

Comment: The linked answer explains how to run psql in a container, so use that to run drop/alter database commands and it’s done?

Comment: What prevents you from running `DROP DATABASE real;` followed by `ALTER DATABASE buffer RENAME TO real;` against your postgres container ?

Comment: @Zeitounator yes I missreaded the thread, because I thought we needed a password and so an interactive console to do a command, seems to be fine without, trying and I will update my question

Comment: you probably need to use pg_dump one way or another.

Comment: @TheFool can you be more precise? any feedback or documentation?