# Trouble executing pg_dump with Python's Docker SDK

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I have a Docker container with PostgreSQL and I want to do a `pg_dump` of my database. I tried with the following code:

```
client = docker.from_env()
postgres = client.containers.get('my_postgres')
command = 'pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://my_user:mypassword@localhost:5432/my_db -Fc > /var/lib/postgresql/data/dumps/test.sql'
log = postgres.exec_run(command, stdout=True, stderr=True)
print(log[1])
```

But I get this error:

```
b'pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is ">")\nTry "pg_dump --help" for more information.\n'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to make a shell command your executable and then pass your whole command to that shell, like this:

```py
command = "sh -c 'pg_dump --dbname .....'"
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438112/bash-docker-exec-file-redirection-from-inside-a-container)

Comment: Spot on. Worked like a champ. May I ask: why are there two set of brackets? Or in other words, why is sh -c separated from the pg_dump part? Thanks