# PostgreSQL: pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Tags: database, postgresql, tar, postgresql-9.5, pg-restore

I'm working through the [Postgres DVD tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/) and am running into issues importing their sample database.

Running `pg_restore -U postgres -d dvdrental ~[filepath]/dvd-database.tar.gz` gives me `pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive`.

My process so far has been the following:

1. Download the [dvdrental.zip](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/?wpdmdl=969) file
2. Extract it to a .tar using `tar czf dvd-database.tar.gz dvdrental.zip` (I've also tried extracting the zip to a folder first with the same result, as well as dropping the .gz)
3. Running `pg_restore -U postgres -d dvdrental ~[filepath]/dvd-database.tar` as stated above.

I'm currently using Postgres 9.5, which may be causing the issue. Looking for an answer that points out where I'm going wrong in this process or how to update an archive of a Postgres database to 9.5.

Comment: I don't think `pg_restore` can handle `.tar.gz`. Did you try just unzipping the archive `unzip dvdrental.zip` and then feed the `.tar` file to `pg_restore`

Comment: Was just about to edit this – I was using tar incorrectly and outputting a gzipped file when I didn't mean to. However, now that I am providing `pg_restore` with an uncompressed tar, I'm getting `pg_restore: [tar archiver] could not find header for file "toc.dat" in tar archive` although the toc.dat is present when the .tar is unpacked.

Comment: then try to unpack the tar and point pg_restore to the directory

Comment: Thank you that worked. Was clearly overthinking this/need to read up on the documentation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Per comments above, the solution was simple.

Extracting the dvdrental.zip file to an uncompressed .tar is not necessary as suggested in the tutorial instructions. `pg_restore` [will work](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgrestore.html) if pointed to the **directory** where the database dump was extracted:

`pg_restore -U <username> -d dvdrental <your/path/to/extracted/dir>/dvdrental`

Comment: If you are on mac having postgres.app
run below and restart terminal.
Then execute command on this post pointing extracted folder.
sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d &&
echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp

ref:
https://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that when installing postgresql, I chose a different name for the superuser (`root` for example, not `postgres`). And the `dvdrental/restore.sql` file uses the `postgres` role.
So to solve this problem you need to create another superuser named `postgres`.

```
createuser --superuser postgres
```

Then create server (PosgreSQL) with role `postgres` and db `dvdrental` with role `postgres`.
After u can succesfuly restore db from extracted folder

Answer (score 0):

After trying for hours which worked for me is the below command. Since PgAdmin 4 it's very hard to work with.

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin/pg_restore -U postgres -p 5433  -d dvdrental /pg-db/dvdrental/
```

Just extract the zip into a folder and execute the `pg_restore` command with these options in my case Mac os where `/pg-db/dvdrental/` is the zip extracted directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your postgres on `Docker` then make sure to pass hostname and port,

```
pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -d dvdrental ./Downloads/dvdrental
```

Here, `./Downloads/dvdrental` is extracted folder from dvdrental.zip

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the reason but this is how it worked for me.

Im using ubuntu 20.04, pgadmin4 version 5.7, postgres version 12.8.

In the "restore" dialog box, "custome and tar", "..." in filename, click upload to upload the tar file, select the uploaded file, then selected the three options: pre-data, data and post-data.
Was getting error: failed with exit code 1.

Deleted the database, again created the database (with the same name), did exactly the same way as before.

This 2nd time it succeeded.
In the logs it executed the following cmd:

```
/usr/bin/pg_restore --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --dbname "mydb" 
--section=pre-data --section=data --section=post-data --verbose "/var/lib/pgadmin/storage/my_email.com/restore_file.tar"
```

Answer (score 0):

To restore an SQL text file into a PostgreSQL database, you can use the `psql` command-line tool, which is commonly used for interacting with PostgreSQL databases. Here are the steps to restore the SQL text file:

1. **Open Command Prompt or Terminal**: Open a command prompt or terminal window on your computer.
2. **Navigate to the Directory**: Use the `cd` command to navigate to the directory where your SQL text file is located.

   ```bash
   cd /path/to/directory
   ```
3. **Log into PostgreSQL**: Use the `psql` command to log into your PostgreSQL database. You'll need to provide the username and database name as arguments. You may also need to enter your password.

   ```bash
   psql -U your_username -d your_database
   ```

   Replace `your_username` with your PostgreSQL username and `your_database` with the name of the database you want to restore the SQL file into.
4. **Execute SQL File**: Once you're logged in, you can execute SQL commands from your text file using the `\i` command followed by the file path:

   ```sql
   \i /path/to/your_sql_file.sql
   ```

   Replace `/path/to/your_sql_file.sql` with the full path to your SQL text file.
5. **Exit psql**: After the SQL file has been executed, you can exit `psql` by typing:

   ```sql
   \q
   ```

   This will return you to the command prompt.

That's it! Your SQL text file has been restored into your PostgreSQL database. Make sure that your SQL file contains valid SQL statements and is compatible with your PostgreSQL database version.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive

Because I exported but did not archive `apple` database to `backup.sql` with [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) as shown below:

```
pg_dump -U john apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dump -U john -Fp apple > backup.sql
```

Then, I tried to import non-archive `backup.sql` to `orange` database with [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) which must be used to import archive files:

```
pg_restore -U john -d orange < backup.sql
```

So, I did it with [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) which must be used to import non-archive files, then I could solve the error. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984733/postgresql-export-database-to-sql-file/77251389#77251389) explains how to export a database and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/77275771#77275771) explains how to import a database:

```
psql -U john -f backup.sql orange
```

Answer (score -2):

It will be easier to use pgAdmin 4.

While restoring the tar file onto the database through pgAdmin you will get this error thrown at you. We usually get stuck at this point and forget to check the schema.

Ignore the error. The data has already been loaded and restored.