# pg_restore works with zip file?

Tags: database, postgresql, pg-restore

Just trying to restore tutorial database from resource:
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/

so, after this code

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d dvdrental /Users/fedotarte/Downloads/dvdrental.zip
```

i got current message:

> pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive

what should i do to restore database successfully?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: unzip it - what's inside?.. tar? dump? compressed dump?..

Comment: [quote from the download page](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/): "*The database file is in zipformat ( dvdrental.zip) so you need to extract it to  dvdrental.tar*". Once you have that, follow the link [loading the sample database into the PostgreSQL database server](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/)

Comment: Hello, @VaoTsun, there are .dat files and restore.sql

Comment: @ArtemFedotov please follow instructions

Comment: @VaoTsun i appreciate your help, the correct answer straitly below the question

Comment: @ArtemFedotov I answered with meant way of restoring. Anyway I'm glad you found your workaround

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.tar is also triggered as a invalid input file, after unzip dvdrental.zip i typed next command(pointed the folder):

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d dvdrental /Users/fedotarte/Downloads/dvdrental
```

And now it works correctly!

P.S.

i duplicated this question:
[Postgres Tutorial: pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246737/postgres-tutorial-pg-restore-archiver-input-file-does-not-appear-to-be-a-val)

Sorry about that....

Comment: I also had to pass host and port as I was running my postgres on Docker.
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d dvdrental ~/Downloads/dvdrental

Answer (score 1):

following the instructions I unzipped the file and after finding a tar file, restored with the command:

```
-bash-4.2$ pg_restore -d dd -F t /tmp/dvdrental.tar
```

so you were meant to specify format tar with `-F t`

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -d dd -c "\dt+"
                          List of relations
 Schema |     Name      | Type  |  Owner   |    Size    | Description
--------+---------------+-------+----------+------------+-------------
 public | actor         | table | postgres | 40 kB      |
 public | address       | table | postgres | 88 kB      |
 public | category      | table | postgres | 8192 bytes |
 public | city          | table | postgres | 64 kB      |
 public | country       | table | postgres | 8192 bytes |
 public | customer      | table | postgres | 96 kB      |
 public | film          | table | postgres | 464 kB     |
 public | film_actor    | table | postgres | 264 kB     |
 public | film_category | table | postgres | 72 kB      |
 public | inventory     | table | postgres | 224 kB     |
 public | language      | table | postgres | 8192 bytes |
 public | payment       | table | postgres | 888 kB     |
 public | rental        | table | postgres | 1224 kB    |
 public | staff         | table | postgres | 16 kB      |
 public | store         | table | postgres | 8192 bytes |
(15 rows)
```