# How can i Dump the generated sql data into my local postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, dump

As an example how want to know how i can migarte my sql data that i previously made a sql dump for my db but now i want to dump the generated sql data into my local postgres

Comment: Possible duplicate [Restore a postgres backup file using the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line)

Comment: there isnt no backup invloved did you read my question.

Comment: Well, in that case: what do you mean by `sql dump` ? And what do you mean by `want to dump the generated sql data into my local postgres` ? To me, that sounds like you want to *restore* it on your local installation.

Comment: A "SQL dump" **is** a backup (taken with `pg_dump`)