# How to back up and restore an *entire* PostgreSQL intallation?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to back up, and then restore, the contents of an **entire** postgres installtion, including all roles, all databases, everything.

During the restore, the target postgres installation shall be **entirely replaced**, so that its state is entirely as specified in the backup, no matter what's on the target postgres installation currently.

Existing answers include [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17740/how-to-get-a-working-and-complete-postgresql-db-backup-and-test), but none of them meets my requirements because

- They use `pg_dump`, forcing me to list the databases manually. I don't want that. I want **all** databases.
- They suggest `pg_dumpall` + `psql`, which doesn't work if the target installation already has (some part of) the tables; typical errors include `ERROR:  role "myuser" cannot be dropped because some objects depend on it`, as a result the table is not dropped, and as a result the eventual `COPY` command importing data fails with e.g. `ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.
- They suggest copying on-disk data files, which doesn't work when you want to backup e.g. from version 9.5 and restore into version 9.6.

How can you backup, and restore, everything in a postgres installation, with one command each?

Comment: I recommend barman here is one tutorial for centos https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-back-up-restore-and-migrate-postgresql-databases-with-barman-on-centos-7

Comment: While barman seems great for a production online backup system of multiple servers, I just want to back up my DB to a file, without setting up a whole standalone backup server solution.

Comment: I think you should try this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ you may get more appropriate attention on your specific request.

Comment: so you want to backup 9.5 database and restore it to 9.6