# What is the purpose of the sql script file in a tar dump?

Tags: postgresql, dump

In [a tar dump](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/dvdrental.zip)

```
$ tar -tf dvdrental.tar 
toc.dat
2163.dat
...
2189.dat
restore.sql
```

After extraction

```
$ file *
2163.dat:    ASCII text
...
2189.dat:    ASCII text
restore.sql: ASCII text, with very long lines
toc.dat:     PostgreSQL custom database dump - v1.12-0
```

1. What is the purpose of `restore.sql`?
2. `toc.dat` is binary, but I can open it and it looks like a sql
   script too. How different are between the purposes of `restore.sql`
   and `toc.dat`?

   The following quote from the document does't answer my question:

   > with  one  file  for  each  table  and  blob  being  dumped,  plus  a  so-called  Table  of  Contents file describing the dumped objects
   >   in a machine-readable format that pg_restore can read.
3. Since a tar dump contains `restore.sql` besides the `.dat` files,
   what is the difference between the sql script files `restore.sql` and `toc.dat` in a tar dump  and a
   plain dump (which has only one sql script file)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `restore.sql` is not used by `pg_restore`. See this comment from `src/bin/pg_dump/pg_backup_tar.c`:

  ```
   *  The tar format also includes a 'restore.sql' script which is there for
   *  the benefit of humans. This script is never used by pg_restore.
  ```
- `toc.dat` is the *table of contents*. It contains commands to create and drop each object in the dump and is used by `pg_restore` to create the objects. It also contains `COPY` statements that load the data from the `*.dat` file.

  You can extract the table of contents in human-readable form with `pg_restore -l`, and you can edit the result to restore only specific objects with `pg_restore -L`.
- The `<number>.dat` files are the files containing the table data, they are used by the `COPY` statements in `toc.dat` and `restore.sql`.

Comment: Thanks. Why does `toc.dat` look like SQL script containing `CREATE DATABASE` and other SQL commands , if it is table of contents?

Comment: After reading the code, it turns out that my answer was quite wrong. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Both `restore.sql` and `toc.dat` are SQL scripts, and what is the difference between them?

Comment: One is used by PostgreSQL, one is nice for you if you want to extract the dump with `tar` and restore it with `psql`.

Comment: Which one is for which? toc.dat for postgresql, and restore.sql for psql?

Comment: See my answer: *`toc.dat` is the table of contents. It contains commands to create and drop each object in the dump and is used by `pg_restore` to create the objects* and *The tar format also includes a `restore.sql` script which is there for the benefit of humans. This script is never used by `pg_restore`.*

Comment: Thank you. (1) What is the difference between `restore.sql`  and the output of  extracting `toc.dat` in human-readable form with `pg_restore -l`? (2) Who will use `restore.sql` and when?

Comment: Use your imagination :^) Someone may want to untar the dump and load it with `psql`.

Comment: This is a directory format dump, if you cd to the directory with toc.dat and *.dat.gz files, "pg_restore -F d -l ." (omit the quotes and mind the .) will give you a list which can prove to you whether you should restore the data using the pg_restore directory format (or not).

Answer (score 1):

This looks a script to restore the data to PostgresQL. the script was created using [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html).

If you'd like to restore, please have a look at [pg_restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line).

The dat files contain the data to be restored in those `\copy` commands in the sql script.

the `toc.dat` file is not referenced inside the sql file. if you try to peek inside using `cat toc.dat|strings` you'll find that it contains data very similar to the sql file, but with a few more [internal ids](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20160126173717.GA565213%40alvherre.pgsql).

I think it might have been intended to work without the SQL at some point, but that's not how it's working right now. see the code to generate toc [here](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/9d4649ca49416111aee2c84b7e4441a0b7aa2fac/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_backup_directory.c).