# pg_restore: [tar archiver] could not find header for file "toc.dat" in tar archive :- [PostgreSQL-11] pg admin 4

Tags: postgresql, database-restore, postgresql-11

Error occured while restoring the PostgreSQL Db

PostgreSQL :- Version : 11
 pgAdmin 4

Refer below image

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue with you!

Answer (score 4):

### In brief

MUST-HAVE **pg_restore** version on localhost matched with the **pg_dump** on machine where the backup is created aka `backup-site`

### In full detail

#### the context

Postgres db backup by **pg_dump** and restore by **pg_restore** [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10781882/248616)

**pg_restore** - We want to restore **backupfile**, ie the .tar file or untar folder of that .tar file, into a local postgres database localdb

**pg_dump** - The backupfile is created using this tool

#### the issue

The pg_restore on our **local machine** may have **version NOT MATCHE**D vs the **pg_dump** version, which was used when creating the backup file

#### solution

Install **pg_restore** on your machine **having the SAME VERSION** on both local machine and on `backup-site`

Comment: That's so wierd, so I want to export my data from a pg 10 to a pg14 instance, but I cannot do so because the pg_dump will always be on ver 10 and my pg_restore on ver 14