# Restoring DB for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am completely new to PG SQL. 
What I need to do is to restore the file from dpexport.pqsql ( i have no idea what is the extension of this file). How do I do it? When I am trying to restore from PG GUI it gives me the error:
"pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql."

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/59724580#59724580