# "stdin is not a tty" when populating Postgres database

Tags: python, database, postgresql, stdin, psql

Please help, I have this `stdin is not a tty` message when i run the command below in my terminal.

```
psql -U postgres kdc < kdc.psql
```

kdc is the database and kdc.psql is the psql file with commands to populate the database. I am in the directory that holds the psql file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what causes that message (it does not happen here), but you should be able to avoid it using the `-f` option:

```bash
psql -U postgres -d kdc -f kdc.psql
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! 
I'm open to understanding why the initial command i used did not work.

Comment: Probably depends on your operating system and your setup. Without more information (file contents, the line that causes the error message) I find it hard to guess what is going on.

Comment: Noted with thanks :)

Comment: A wild guess is that something in the SQL file (SELECT statement, psql \foo command) tried to display data, triggering the pager. *If* that is the case, then `psql -U postgres -P pager kdc < kdc.psql` should work.

Comment: @TurePålsson Normally `psql` will detect that standard input is not a terminal and *not* invoke the pager.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-f` or `--file` for `kdc.psql` because on Windows, `<` doesn't work to import a file while `>` works to export a database. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/77275771#77275771) explains how to import a backup file into a database:

```
psql -U postgres -f kdc.psql kdc
```

Or:

```
psql -U postgres -d kdc -f kdc.psql
```

Or:

```
psql -U postgres --file kdc.psql kdc
```

Or:

```
psql -U postgres -d kdc --file kdc.psql
```